# How to make ondblclick event works on phone?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to achieve the double click event on a specific div like this:

```
<div   id="divID" ondblclick = 'alert("double click!!");' >
```

it worked on the google chrome browser but when I open it with phone it didn't work, by the way the single click worked.

ps: i added this two things

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1,user-scalable=no">
```

and this

```
body {
-ms-touch-action: manipulation;
touch-action: manipulation;}
```

but it didnt work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load jQuery Mobile into your project and try using `taphold` or some of the other mobile specific touch events that are available to you through that API.

Here's the jQuery Mobile documentation with all the events you can use: http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/

Comment: Thank you i added an external function called 'doubletap' and it worked.

Comment: Adding a full library with tons of features just for this purpose to me it seems  really unnecessary with performace drawback

Answer (score 5):

I got the same issue. On touch devices, if you want to detect a double-tap gesture and you use the ondblclick event in most cases it will not work and also the problem is it will also fire an onclick. One of the solution is to implement a double tap detection pattern using the following code sample:

```
var doubletapDeltaTime_ = 700;
var doubletap1Function_ = null;
var doubletap2Function_ = null;
var doubletapTimer = null;

function tap(singleTapFunc, doubleTapFunc) {
    if (doubletapTimer==null) {
    // First tap, we wait X ms to the second tap
        doubletapTimer_ = setTimeout(doubletapTimeout_, doubletapDeltaTime_);
        doubletap1Function_ = singleTapFunc;
        doubletap2Function_ = doubleTapFunc;
    } else {
    // Second tap
        clearTimeout(doubletapTimer);
        doubletapTimer_ = null;
        doubletap2Function_();
    }
}

function doubletapTimeout() {
// Wait for second tap timeout
    doubletap1Function_();
    doubleTapTimer_ = null;
}
```

And you can call it like

```
<div   id="divID" onclick="tap(tapOnce, tapTwice)" >
```

tapOnce and tapTwice are your functions which will be called in respective cases. This solution will work on browsers too.

[Reference](http://mscerts.programming4.us/programming/coding%20javascript%20for%20mobile%20browsers%20(part%2010)%20-%20event%20handling.aspx#XfmdMwR1UcS6W5M4.99)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Using jQuery just for this purpose doesn't sound good.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the external function 'doubletap' which can be helpful:

```
/*
 * jQuery Double Tap
 * Developer: Sergey Margaritov (sergey@margaritov.net)
 * Date: 22.10.2013
 * Based on jquery documentation http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-extensions/
 */

(function($){

  $.event.special.doubletap = {
    bindType: 'touchend',
    delegateType: 'touchend',

    handle: function(event) {
      var handleObj   = event.handleObj,
          targetData  = jQuery.data(event.target),
          now         = new Date().getTime(),
          delta       = targetData.lastTouch ? now - targetData.lastTouch : 0,
          delay       = delay == null ? 300 : delay;

      if (delta < delay && delta > 30) {
        targetData.lastTouch = null;
        event.type = handleObj.origType;
        ['clientX', 'clientY', 'pageX', 'pageY'].forEach(function(property) {
          event[property] = event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0][property];
        })

        // let jQuery handle the triggering of "doubletap" event handlers
        handleObj.handler.apply(this, arguments);
      } else {
        targetData.lastTouch = now;
      }
    }
  };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet for TS React users. Pass in the click event, so that double click is only invoked if the same element is clicked twice

```
import React from "react";

type CallBack = () => any;
type TapParams = { onSingleTap?: CallBack; onDoubleTap?: CallBack };

var DELTA_TIME_THRESHOLD_MS = 700;
var timer: NodeJS.Timeout | null = null;
var target: EventTarget;

export function tap(
  e: React.MouseEvent,
  { onSingleTap, onDoubleTap }: TapParams
) {

  if (timer == null) {
    // First tap
    onSingleTap?.();

    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      timer = null;
    }, DELTA_TIME_THRESHOLD_MS);
  } else {
    // Second tap
    if (e.target === target) {
      onDoubleTap?.();
    }

    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = null;
  }
  target = e.target;
}
```

Usage

```
<div
  onClick={(e) => tap(e, { onSingleTap, onDoubleTap })}
>Tap or doubletap</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using only JavaScript**

You can use "touchstart" event for a single touch,
but with calculating the time when he should click again

I used 400 (0.4s) as it's the longer duration between two touches
It's only an estimate, but it's still a reasonable time

```
let expired

let doubleClick = function () {
    console.log('double click')
}

let doubleTouch = function (e) {
    if (e.touches.length === 1) {
        if (!expired) {
            expired = e.timeStamp + 400
        } else if (e.timeStamp <= expired) {
            // remove the default of this event ( Zoom )
            e.preventDefault()
            doubleClick()
            // then reset the variable for other "double Touches" event
            expired = null
        } else {
            // if the second touch was expired, make it as it's the first
            expired = e.timeStamp + 400
        }
    }
}

let element = document.getElementById('btn')
element.addEventListener('touchstart', doubleTouch)
element.addEventListener('dblclick', doubleClick)
```

**In case of this error :**
*Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.*

event.preventDefault( ) not working if element = "document" or "document.body"
So the solution of that, you should have a full page div container :

```
let element = document.getElementById('container')
element.style.minWidth = '100vw'
element.style.minHeight = '100vh'
document.body.style.margin = '0px'
element.addEventListener('touchstart', elementTouch)
element.addEventListener('dblclick', doubleClick)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need simple pure js then try something like this [gist](https://gist.github.com/toorajam/0c7fc1f9eeb854334757b56b497af43b).

Answer (score 0):

I created this based off the answer @planet260 gave; this one actually works though. It uses Typescript, but you can just remove the typing if you're using JS. You can also play with the time delta (how long to wait for the 2nd tap). Personally, 300ms feels pretty natural to me.

```
let tapTimer: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>| null = null
export function tap(singleTapFunc: Function, doubleTapFunc: Function) {
  const dblTapDelta = 300
  function dblTapTimeout() {
    singleTapFunc()
    tapTimer = null;
  }
  if (!tapTimer) {
    tapTimer = setTimeout(dblTapTimeout, dblTapDelta)
  } else {
    clearTimeout(tapTimer)
    tapTimer = null
    doubleTapFunc()
  }
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
<div onClick={() => tap(
    () => console.log('SINGLE CLICK'),
    () => console.log('DOUBLE CLICK'),
)}></div>
```