# To run a function on double click/tap for both desktop browsers and mobile devices

Tags: jquery, double-click

I have the following jQuery code in a web app that runs a function on a double click. It works well on desktop browsers. Now I want to develop the code further so that it also works on mobile devices with double tap. How can I do that?

Here is my HTML image:

```
<img ondblclick="imgDblClick()" src="Image2.png" />
```

And here is the jQuery script:

```
function imgDblClick() {    
    alert("Image double clicked");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make ondblclick event works on phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28940676/how-to-make-ondblclick-event-works-on-phone)

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058241/touch-device-single-and-double-tap-events-handler-jquery-javascript